# What is the molecular formula of 2-ethynyloctahydro-1H-indene?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I thought the formula for this $\ce{C11H15}$, but it's not. I need assistance in finding the proper formula:

[image: 2-ethynyloctahydro-1H-indene]

Comment: You forgot the $\ce{H}$ on the triple bond! :-)

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you forgot one hydrogen at the terminal carbon in alkyne group $\ce{R-C#C-H}$. With this in mind the formula would be $\ce{C11H16}$:

[image: Structure with implicit hydrogens]